# node.js & socket.io using client specific variables

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 
    var clientid = client.sessionId;
  console.log('Connection from '+clientid);

  var player = 0;
  client.on('message',function(data){ 
    HandleClientData(data,clientid);
  });
  client.on('disconnect',function(){
    console.log('Server has disconnected');
  });  
});
```

Is the variable "player" unique to the client?
How can I get/set this variable from another function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a variable local to the anonymous function that runs when a socket connection is established. If you want to read it from another function, either move it into the global scope or pass it into that function as one of its arguments. If you want to set it from another function, either move it to the global scope or pass it into that function and read its value when that function returns.

If you explain what you want to use `player` for, there's probably a much clearer answer.

Comment: Let's say that the variable is a player location that I want to manipulate in other functions. If i set it in global scope, is that still unique to the client? Also, how do I even put it in the global scope :S. Very hard to find documentation for node.

Comment: This isn't a node question/situation, this is just javascript. Node is just a few libraries for javascript. Don't look for node help, just a javascript book. It would not be a global unless it was an array indexed by clientid or something like that, otherwise it'd be shared.

Comment: I guess I had presumed this was all too good to be true. Thanks I have a better understanding now. Learn more javascript, not more nodejs

Answer (score 2):

what about this:

```
socket.on('connection', function(client){
client.player = 0;
console.log('Connection from '+client.clientid);

client.on('message',function(data){
    someOtherFunctions(this.player); 
    HandleClientData(data,this.clientid);
});
client.on('disconnect',function(){
  console.log(this.clientid+' has been disconnected');
  });  
});
```

You can define any data individually for the connected sockets and use them in other callbacks with "this" scope. "this" refers to the current socket